# No JobTracker and NameNode Stop while running the command stop-all.sh

Tags: hadoop

In My case jobtracker and namenode started but unable to stop it by running stop-all.sh command

When I type jps got the following message :

```
[root@iq hadoop]# jps

25258 JobTracker

8082 SecondaryNameNode

7944 DataNode

8404 Jps

8321 TaskTracker

24237 NameNode
```

But when I try to stop it by running stop-all.sh on command line got the following message :

```
[root@iq bin]# bash stop-all.sh 

no jobtracker to stop

localhost: stopping tasktracker

no namenode to stop

localhost: stopping datanode

localhost: stopping secondarynamenode
```

When I check the running job again by typing jps on command line, got the following :

```
[root@iq bin]# jps

11823 Jps

25258 JobTracker

24237 NameNode
```

Its seem that JobTracker and NameNode are not stop, Could any one please help me out.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet, let me know whenever you got solution. thanks

Comment: I traced the log files on this error.  I get a namenode exception : Cannot lock storage /home/hadoop/hdfs/name and that the directory is already locked. Interestingly, this happens when I do stop-dfs.sh (and the stack trace has some dfs-init like function signature).  See http://pastebin.com/vUyBdyzx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens with hadoop 1.1.2 when the pid saved in /tmp/*.pid file does not match the actual pid of the namenode.

I opened stop-dfs.sh,  it appeared to call something like this:

```
/opt/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /opt/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/ stop namenode
```

This one failed as well.  Then on inspection of the code, it seems the script itself was doing a kill -9 of the hadoop daemon.

After manually killing the daemon tasks (did not need signal 9) - I was able to start and stop the dfs correctly using the stop-dfs.sh script.  This problem did not show up afterwards.